# Progressive Web Appss and In App purchases/billing

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Good day,
I wanted to know how possible it is to have in app purchases/billing in a PWA app? if so can I get a reference to how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.
Godfrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short answer, yes.

It is completely possible make purchases available in Progressive Web Apps (PWA) because of the [Payment Request API](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/) or if you are looking for a service, you could implement [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/) or something similar.

I don't understand how you couldn't figure this out on your own. It seems like you do not understand PWAs very well. A PWA is "a web app that uses modern web capabilities to deliver an app-like experience to users" so basically there's no reason why any feature that is not available on the web could not be available on a PWA.

You always have the capability make your web app a PWA but it is impossible to make your PWA a web app because it already would be.

Read More about PWAs at https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/what-are-progressive-web-apps

Comment: The "Payment Request API" link is dead, could you recheck @ShadowDev.

Comment: Error on the page "500 Unexpected end of file", another link would be nice. @ShadowDev

Comment: Link works just fine for me but I can update it with another link

Comment: yep no problem :)

Comment: @devwk Your link is for IOS apps. What about Android?

Comment: @FullOfStack Updated.

Comment: "so basically there's no reason why any feature that is not available on the web could not be available on a PWA" 
I find this confusing. Did you mean: "any feature that *IS* available on the web could not be available on a PWA"?