# Implementing IAP for a WebApp (pwa) on ios/Apple

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I am having a hard time finding an answer whether it is possible to implement in-app-purchases for a web-based application on **ios**.

Apple's guidelines, similar to Google's pretty much say, "If you publish your app on our store, and offer the purchase of digital goods, you need to use our IAP implementation".

So my simple question is: **HOW** or can I implement IAP for a non-native but web based app for **IOS**, or is it just simply not possible?

For the Play Store there seems to be no issue, I found this explaining exactly how to iplement Play Billing.

Everything else I can find on this topic, is either [not specific to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842172/progressive-web-appss-and-in-app-purchases-billing) or just [simply ignored](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698143) (which I hope won't happen to my question ;P)

If there is no possible option, what alternatives are there? Can I alternatively to a PWA, maybe use something like [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) to access the native payment API on ios?

**Edit**:
Capacitor definetly seems to be [an option](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/in-app-purchases), but still, I am curious about PWA support on Apple's side.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? The information around seems very sparse, so my guess is that no. Will adding Apple Pay allow the app to be accepted in the app store?

Comment: @Yon unfortunately not, i did not find time yet to dive deeper into this

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the native platform so I think you have to use ionic/capacitor.

Recently found this: https://www.revenuecat.com/. Looks like it makes the whole process much simpler. They have a nice ionic guide